# Iterating through a Lists

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 Lists:

1. List l
2. List d

The 1) List is populated with text. The 2nd List has elements inserted into it. WordCount is a class below

```
class WordCount
{
string word;
int count;
}
```

I have 2 questions:
1. If I have the below foreach loop,

```
foreach (WordCount currWord in d)
{
currWord.count+=1;
}
```

Is this the proper code to increment each WordCount's `count` variable by 1?

2nd question, I will be inserting elements into List d, how can I insert the new elements in alphabetical order of `word` ?

I am asking 2 really specific and basic questions that will help me solve my problem. I won't go in detail as to what my problem is because last SO question caused a lot of unwanted coding answers. If someone can help me with this then I can do the rest to solving my coding problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) yes or you can say

```
currWord.count++;
```

2) You can try and use a [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this

```
SortedList<string, WordCount> yourList= new SortedList<string, WordCount>();
yourLIst.Add(myword.word, myword);
```

This is somewhat redundant though. It would be better to just have the count as the value in the list and use the word itself as the key. That eliminates the need for your custom class

Comment: how do I select the word as the type to sort by?

Comment: @HarrisCalvin I have added it to the answer

Comment: how would it look if I use the SortedList with <string, int> ? Meaning using word as key and count as value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is the correct way. You can shorten it to:

```
currWord.count++;
```

`SortedList<TKey, TValue>` is an option if you want to insert elements into a list and have them sorted for you.

[See the MSDN Documentation on SortedList here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Simin Whitehead how do I select the word as the type to sort by?